# Non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, regression, interaction, model, contingency-tables

I'm trying to find out a model that adequately describes effects of gender and length on food choice. For gender; 0=Male and 1=Female, length; 0=Subadult 1=Adult, Choice; F=Fish I=Invertebrates and O=Others.

Here is  my data;

```
    data3 <- data.frame(
  gender = c(0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1, 1, 
             1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,1), 
  length = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  choice = c("I","F", "F","F", "I","F","I","F", "I","I","I", "O","O","I","F","F","I","O","F","O","F","F","I","F","I",
             "F","F","F","F","F","O","O",
             "F","F","F","F", "O","F","F","I","I","I","O","I","I","I","F","I","O","I","I","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","O","F","I",
             "F","F")
)
```

Then I want to find a model that describes the effects of gender and length on food choice. Here's what I did.

```
m1 <- loglm( choice ~ length+gender, data3)

summary(m1)
```

But it doesn't work and I have the next error message :

```
Error in observed - expected : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In loglin(data, margins, start = start, fit = fitted, param = param,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Could someone help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: Also, I think the model call is not correct for what you want to do.  Try:  `Table = xtabs(~ length + gender + choice, data=data3); ftable(Table); model = loglm(~ length + gender + choice, Table); summary(model)`

Comment: There is a statistical question here, as log-linear models don't necessarily specify certain variables as the independent variables or as the dependent variable.  Instead, they test for association (like a chi-square test of association).  From the description, it sounds like something more like multinomial logistic regression is the appropriate model.  Though simpler approaches like the analysis of smaller contingency tables might be preferable.